# Please specify the error in this octave code

Tags: octave

So I am trying to solve this problem from coursera regarding onevsAll classification. It comes under the ml course under Andrew NG. I am not able to find mistake in my code and it keeps showing this error

```
error: fmincg: operator +: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 401x1, op2 is 4x1)
error: called from
    fmincg at line 87 column 5
    oneVsAll at line 60 column 13
    ex3 at line 77 column 13
```

I have tried reading the `fmincg` code but I cannot understand the problem.

```matlab
function [all_theta] = oneVsAll(X, y, num_labels, lambda)


% Some useful variables
m = size(X, 1);
n = size(X, 2);

% You need to return the following variables correctly
all_theta = zeros(num_labels, n + 1);

% Add ones to the X data matrix
X = [ones(m, 1) X];


    for c = 1:num_labels
    initial_theta = zeros(n+1,1) ;
     options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 50);
    [theta] = fmincg (@(t)(lrCostFunction(t, X, (y == c), lambda)),initial_theta, options); 
    all_theta(c, :) = theta;
end;
```

Program is showing error mentioned above regarding the `fmincg` file.

Comment: What excactly do you not understand? The shown error is pretty descriptive, isn't it? Are the shown sizes of the operands as you would expect?

Comment: presumably what you're passing to fmincg is the wrong shape for what you expect to happen. For example, I note that your `initial_theta` is (n+1)x1, whereas your `theta` output is (presumably) expected to be 1x(n+1)?